# Django session timeout after 10 minutes in some browsers while it is valid for one day(in settings.py)

Tags: django, session, cookies

I am using Django Basic authentication and Session authentication inbuilt API.In my application I have given a session timeout value of 24 hours in settings.py.
It is working fine but in some chrome browsers it is doing session timeout at every 10-15 minutes.
I have checked session cookie after successful login it is showing correct expiry date.but after 10-15 minutes when session timeouts, cookie expiry date automatically changes.
Please reply if someone has faced some issue.

Comment: Please provide some code so people can check what you're doing exactly

Comment: using these classes in settings.py                       
          REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
                )
        } and SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=86400

Comment: I am working on angularjs web project.The back-end is Django REST API.We are using inbuilt Session Authentication API in our project.I have provided session timeout value of 1day in setting.py.My application is working fine but in some chrome browsers we are facing an issue of session timeout after 10-15 minutes.I have analysed this issue and observed that Session cookie expiry date value was correct.But still session timeouts automatically.I have checked my settings.py no setting for auto timeout is enabled.